# how can i acces the control on label text dropdown list event selection in the gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i want to change the price of the item only whose number of  quantity gets changed in the dropdown list .

[image]

But i am not able to access the label.text property in the "protected void 
DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)" event.

[image]

the html code of the grid view is as

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the future: Please provide the code as actual text inline with the question instead of a screenshot. You can also add images directly to the question instead of via imgur.

Regarding your problem: You need to use the [FindControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2) method of the Grid like this: `GridView1.FindControl(lblprice)` to get a reference to the label. With that you can access its text

Comment: i want code like this but it gives  error                                                             
  protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblprice.text *= DropDownList1.Selectevalue; 
}